# NoReverseMatch Django: keyword arguments

Tags: django, django-urls

Why does this return `NoReverseMatch`?

html:

```
{% url vote thing.id thing.slug %}
```

urls.py:

```
url(r'^vote/(?P<object_id>\d+)/(?P<slug>[w\-]+)/$', 'app.views.the_view', name='vote'),
```

views.py:

```
def the_view(request, object_id, slug):
    thing_list = Thing.objects.all()
    return render(request, 'vote.html', {'thing_list':thing_list})
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you must use the following:

```
{% url vote object_id=thing.id slug=thing.slug %}
```

since you have explicitly named the matched groups in your pattern.

Note that starting from Django 1.5 you must do:

```
{% url 'vote' .. %}
```

instead of:

```
{% url vote ..%}
```

See it in the django docs here https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/templates/builtins/?from=olddocs#url

Comment: Thanks I tried using keyword arguments as you suggested, but still am getting NoReverseMatch. Any other ideas of what may be the culprit? Thank you

Comment: do you have any other urls defined in your patterns list as well? A common mistake is placing wide-matching patterns before narrow patterns (e.g. if r'^(?P<whatever>.*)/$' is listed before r'^vote/$') resulting in a constant match of the first pattern.